# how to merge/append one file content to another file using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, merge-file

I have two file fileA and fileB

`FileA` content

```
PersonName Value1 Value2 Value3
```

`FileB` content

```
ALBERT check1 check1 check1
ALBERT check2 check2 check2
ALBERT check3 check3 check3
```

I want to merge content of fileA and fileB and FileA content should be the first line in the merged file

I tried using `paste` and `sort` command... not not able to get required result
any suggestions...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
cat FileA FileB > NewFile
```

or

```
cat FileA > NewFile
cat FileB >> NewFile
```

Comment: Yes, this is a useful use of cat

Comment: wondering why this ever was is the up voted answer?  The question was append one file to another, not create a new file.  The newer answer above using tee is correct for the question.

Answer (score 7):

In Unix/Linux you can use the command cat

Example:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

*This will put the contents of file1 and file2 into file3.*

```
cat file1.txt >> file2.txt
```

*This will add the information from file1.txt to the information already existing in file2.txt*

Answer (score 1):

`cat FileA | tee -a FileB`

```
$ cat FileA
PersonName Value1 Value2 Value3
$ cat FileB
ALBERT check1 check1 check1
ALBERT check2 check2 check2
ALBERT check3 check3 check3
$ cat FileA | tee -a FileB
ALBERT check1 check1 check1
ALBERT check2 check2 check2
ALBERT check3 check3 check3
PersonName Value1 Value2 Value3
```

Comment: `cat FileA | tee -a FileB > /dev/null`  add `/dev/null` to suppress the cat of FileA, tee being ...well... tee.   It is possible to make a temporary file and copy over FileB instead but this is simple.